Gfci - receptacle- motion sensor light in the attic?
Im trying to wire a GFCI in my bathroom. So I have a line coming in and a load to the next receptacle in The bathroom it has a line (after the gfci is on ) and a load that goes to a motion sensor light in my attic. Why won’t the gfci reset when I wire it as such? If I stop at the second receptacle it’s fine so where do I wire the light in the attic on the second receptacle?

You may be getting line and load confused. The motion sensor may be a switch loop. All kinds of possibilities. Pictures of the wiring would help.

You can't just put an attic light on any circuit.  It is not allowed on circuits which power kitchen or bathroom general-use receptacles. Additionally, a laundry and garage must have one 20A receptacle circuit which powers only loads in that room, so you can't tap those circuits either.  Use a general lighting circuit.
